# jquery steps briefly shows next step when next button is clicked

Tags: jquery, wizard, jquery-steps

i am using jquery steps. when i click the next button to view the next step, i briefly see the next step load under the current step. i'm using the default logic provided by the steps example page, but it is not adding the slide effect for the step even though i am declaring `transitionEffect: "slideLeft"` - so what am i missing here?

here is a [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/zachisit/2swvkerv/)

any help would be greatly appreciated